# Adding Audio functionality in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I have added a custom `ListView` with a button that should play different audios in each row. This is the code that i have written for it. But it is not working properly.
`Onclicklistener` is not working. Please Help!

CustomListAdapter.class

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<String> data;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> image_bit;
private static ArrayList<String> audio_bit;
private MediaPlayer player;

private static LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity acivity, ArrayList<String> data,ArrayList<Bitmap> image_bit,ArrayList<String>audio) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.activity = acivity;
    this.data = data;
    this.image_bit=image_bit;
    this.audio_bit=audio;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) acivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ListCell listCell;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listact_kitchen, null);
        listCell = new ListCell();
        listCell.tvStep = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvStep);
        listCell.list_image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        listCell.imageButton1=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        convertView.setTag(listCell);
    }
    else
    {
        listCell = (ListCell) convertView.getTag();
    }

    try
    {
        listCell.tvStep.setText(data.get(position));
        listCell.list_image.setImageBitmap(image_bit.get(position));
        listCell.imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                player=new MediaPlayer();
                     try {
                        player.setDataSource(audio_bit.get(position));
                        player.prepare();
                        player.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 


            }
        });


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return convertView;
}

private class ListCell
{
    TextView tvStep;
    ImageView list_image;
    Button imageButton1;
}

}
```

This is the latest logcat

```
04-22 12:06:35.618: I/Process(5129): Sending signal. PID: 5129 SIG: 9
04-22 12:06:35.998: D/PackageItemInfo(6020): loadIcon(cached)name=org.example.beproj.MainActivity
04-22 12:06:40.553: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 390K, 42% free 9839K/16688K, paused 24ms, total 31ms
04-22 12:06:40.573: I/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.715MB for 8294416-byte allocation
04-22 12:06:40.593: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_CONCURRENT freed 18K, 28% free 17921K/24792K, paused 6ms+2ms, total 21ms
04-22 12:06:40.803: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 34K, 28% free 17921K/24792K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
04-22 12:06:40.823: I/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Grow heap (frag case) to 27.608MB for 8294416-byte allocation
04-22 12:06:40.843: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 21% free 26021K/32896K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 24ms
04-22 12:06:41.074: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 33K, 21% free 26022K/32896K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
04-22 12:06:41.084: I/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Grow heap (frag case) to 35.519MB for 8294416-byte allocation
04-22 12:06:41.134: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 17% free 34122K/41000K, paused 4ms+9ms, total 42ms
04-22 12:06:41.414: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 32K, 17% free 34122K/41000K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
04-22 12:06:41.424: I/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Grow heap (frag case) to 43.429MB for 8294416-byte allocation
04-22 12:06:41.454: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 15% free 42222K/49104K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 24ms
04-22 12:06:41.644: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 33K, 15% free 42222K/49104K, paused 15ms, total 16ms
04-22 12:06:41.664: I/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Grow heap (frag case) to 51.339MB for 8294416-byte allocation
04-22 12:06:41.704: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 13% free 50322K/57208K, paused 3ms+12ms, total 40ms
04-22 12:06:41.915: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 34K, 13% free 50323K/57208K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
04-22 12:06:41.925: I/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Grow heap (frag case) to 59.250MB for 8294416-byte allocation
04-22 12:06:41.965: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 11% free 58423K/65312K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 36ms
04-22 12:06:42.195: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 32K, 11% free 58423K/65312K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
04-22 12:06:42.225: I/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Grow heap (frag case) to 67.161MB for 8294416-byte allocation
04-22 12:06:42.285: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 10% free 66523K/73416K, paused 3ms+21ms, total 62ms
04-22 12:06:42.485: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 34K, 10% free 66524K/73416K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
04-22 12:06:42.515: I/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Grow heap (frag case) to 75.072MB for 8294416-byte allocation
04-22 12:06:42.575: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 9% free 74624K/81520K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 59ms
04-22 12:06:42.785: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 32K, 9% free 74624K/81520K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
04-22 12:06:42.836: I/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Grow heap (frag case) to 82.982MB for 8294416-byte allocation
04-22 12:06:42.886: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 82724K/89624K, paused 5ms+20ms, total 46ms
04-22 12:06:43.066: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 33K, 8% free 82724K/89624K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
04-22 12:06:43.126: I/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Grow heap (frag case) to 90.892MB for 8294416-byte allocation
04-22 12:06:43.176: I/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Clamp target GC heap from 96.892MB to 96.000MB
04-22 12:06:43.176: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 90824K/97728K, paused 4ms+6ms, total 55ms
04-22 12:06:43.356: I/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Clamp target GC heap from 96.893MB to 96.000MB
04-22 12:06:43.356: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 33K, 8% free 90825K/97728K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
04-22 12:06:43.356: I/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 8294416-byte allocation
04-22 12:06:43.386: I/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Clamp target GC heap from 96.885MB to 96.000MB
04-22 12:06:43.386: D/dalvikvm(6020): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 8% free 90815K/97728K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
04-22 12:06:43.386: E/dalvikvm-heap(6020): Out of memory on a 8294416-byte allocation.
04-22 12:06:43.386: I/dalvikvm(6020): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
04-22 12:06:43.386: I/dalvikvm(6020):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41277b50 self=0x412671d0
04-22 12:06:43.386: I/dalvikvm(6020):   | sysTid=6020 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075481820
04-22 12:06:43.386: I/dalvikvm(6020):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=215 stm=39 core=0
04-22 12:06:43.386: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
04-22 12:06:43.386: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:529)
04-22 12:06:43.386: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:302)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:328)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at org.example.beproj.change.ImgBitmap(change.java:97)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at org.example.beproj.change.onCreate(change.java:55)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5117)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
04-22 12:06:43.396: I/dalvikvm(6020):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 12:06:43.396: D/skia(6020): --- decoder->decode returned false
04-22 12:06:43.396: D/AndroidRuntime(6020): Shutting down VM
04-22 12:06:43.396: W/dalvikvm(6020): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41276ae0)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:529)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:302)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:328)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at org.example.beproj.change.ImgBitmap(change.java:97)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at org.example.beproj.change.onCreate(change.java:55)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5117)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
04-22 12:06:43.406: E/AndroidRuntime(6020):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you get any excpetion? Can you post the output from **logcat** please?

Comment: What is the issue you facing?

Comment: First ensure, your onClick() method is getting called. Have a toast/log there to ensure. 
And also "not working properly" is not a way to solve problems. You need to say what is not working.

Comment: Does it give an exception? Or not? Please give some more information about 'not working'

Comment: put android:focusableInTouchMode="false" for button in  xml file.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button this is the issue. in xml you have set as imagebutton but in code you are declaring and using it as button

Answer (score 0):

Currently issue may that you will not be getting the position inside onclicklistener.

set the position in imageButton1 tag as

```
listCell.imageButton1.setTag (position);
```

Inside on click listener retrieve it as

```
int position = Integer.valueOf(v.getTag());
```

So your onclicklistener will look like this

```
listCell.imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
         int position = Integer.valueOf(v.getTag());
         player=new MediaPlayer();
         try {
               player.setDataSource(audio_bit.get(position));
               player.prepare();
               player.start();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } 
    }
 });
```

Comment: i have put the logcat